# HBase qualifier filter vs. value filter performance

Tags: hbase

The use case -
An HBase table with millions of rows.
Keys are hashed for write distribution. 
Need to scan the whole table and process a sub-set of the rows based on a specific value.

Now there are two options of how to keep the value -
1. value is the value of a column (column X = value)
2. value is the column qualifier.

In option 1 (using a column value) scanning and filtering according to the value will use SingleColumnValueFilter.
In option 2 it will use QualifierFilter that should only check for the existence of the qualifier.

The question is whether there's a performance difference between these two options. Is the QualifierFilter supposed to have better performance? Is checking for a qualifier existence is less expensive than checking for the column value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both QualiferFilter and ValueFilter look at all the cells (one looks at the keys the other in the values - see below) so they'd have the same performance

QualiferFilter:

```
@Override
  public ReturnCode filterKeyValue(Cell v) {
    int qualifierLength = v.getQualifierLength();
    if (qualifierLength > 0) {
      if (doCompare(this.compareOp, this.comparator, v.getQualifierArray(),
          v.getQualifierOffset(), qualifierLength)) {
        return ReturnCode.SKIP;
      }
    }
    return ReturnCode.INCLUDE;
  }
```

ValueFilter:

```
 @Override
  public ReturnCode filterKeyValue(Cell v) {
    if (doCompare(this.compareOp, this.comparator, v.getValueArray(),
        v.getValueOffset(), v.getValueLength())) {
      return ReturnCode.SKIP;
    }
    return ReturnCode.INCLUDE;
  }
```